# /proc/net/tcp cannot be read

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

As root:

```
root@xxxx:~# ls -l /proc/net/tcp
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun  4 17:19 /proc/net/tcp
```

As a normal user:

```
production@xxxx:~$ ls -l /proc/net/tcp
ls: cannot access /proc/net/tcp: No such file or directory
```

2 questions:

1. why can't I read the file as a normal user despite having the right permissions?
2. how can I make that damn box allow me to read the file as a normal user?

Obviously, I can't pay answers with a beer, but if you happen to live next to Nice in France, I can do something :)

Answer (score 3):

To make a long story short, this is due to the kernel that is installed on that box. It uses the [grsec patches](https://wiki.debian.org/grsecurity) that disallow this specific operation, to "improve" security.

The fix is thus one of:

1. run your program as root
2. install a saner kernel (say, the default Ubuntu kernel)

Answer (score 1):

This should usually be accessible to users.

Please check the permission of the directory...

```
ls -ld /proc/net
```

...to see what you get.

This is a virtual filesystem, so you cannot really change its permissions in most cases.

The state might somehow have gotten corrupted. In that case, you might have to reboot the server to fix it.